# Calculating time taken and distance

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics, kinematics

> A car accelerates from $10 \text{ m/s}$ to $ 60 \text{ m/s}$ at an acceleration of $10 \text{ m/s$^2$}$. Calculate the time taken for this acceleration to occur and the distance the car has traveled in time.

I know that the acceleration is $10 \text{ m/s$^2$}$ and the initial velocity is $10 \text{ m/s}$ and the final velocity is $60 \text{ m/s}$.

However, I am unsure whether to use the equation $v = u + at$ or the equation $s = ut + \frac {1}{2}at^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. You know that $u=10$, $v=60$, $a=10$

In the equation v=u+at the only thing you're missing is time so that formula can be used to get the time taken.

The other formula will be useful once you know the time taken.

Comment: So the final answers I got were time taken is 5[s] and the distance is 175[m^2], however it is asking for the distance the car has travelled in time so would I have to convert the 175[m^2] to time ? And if so how would I do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

v = u + at is the equation you will want to use.

Answer (score 1):

1) to calculate time t use first law of motion, $v=u+at$,
$$60=10+10t$$
$$t=\frac{50}{10}=5 sec$$
2) to calculate distance s traveled in time $t=5sec$ use 2nd law of motion, $s=ut+\frac12 at^2$, 
$$s=10\cdot 5+\frac12 \cdot 10\cdot 5^2=175 m$$

Comment: For the second equation should the answer not be 175[m^2] rather than 140[m]?

Comment: i am sorry, you are correct, it is 175 m, again sorry for this silly mistake

Comment: It's fine haha but I just wanted to ask can you leave the answer for distance in units of [m] as the question says the distance the car has travelled in time. Would you have to convert this into time or could you just leave the answer as it is ? Thanks.

Comment: distance traveled in time is the distance which car traveled in 5 sec i.e. time required to accelerate from 10 m/s to 60 m/s. read carefully the accepted answer. he is also saying the same thing that's first you calculate time then distance traveled in that time using your second equation